# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime when converting a string to date given by user in api

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures

I'm using ASP.NET MVC API and MS SQL database.

My input through the API is the string

```
arrivalOnScene: "13/01/2021 17:35:38".
```

In the controller I have the following script:

```
var insert_query = entities.Database.SqlQuery<Call_Info_Timings>("exec [dbo].[insert_call_info_timings] @call_id, @user_id, @arrivalOnScene,
                            new SqlParameter("call_id", call_id),
                            new SqlParameter("user_id", u_id),
                            new SqlParameter("ambulanceNum", ambulanceNum),
                            new SqlParameter("arrivalOnScene", DateTime.Parse(arrivalOnScene, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)))
```

When trying to call the stored-procedure `insert_call_info_timings` I get the error:

> System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

The valid dateTime format in my database would be `2021-01-13 17:35:38`.

Can you help me please?

Comment: `DateTime` has no format, it's a binary value. Neither do the `date`, `datetime`, `datetime2` or `datetimeoffset` types. The string format you used is a localized format whose parsing is affected by the current thread's locale - there's no reason to use. `CurrentCulture`, that's the default. I suspect the machine runs on a US locale and tried to treat `13` as the month. Don't use localized strings

Comment: Where does the input come from? You should try to avoid strings as much as possible, eg by using a. date picker control. If you can't use the ISO8601 format wherever possible. If you can't do that either, you *have* to know what the input's locale is, and use the matching CultureInfo

Comment: BTW `DateTime.Parse` will recognize the ISO8601 format, even the looser `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss` form, no mater what culture is used

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thank you! The input comes from a android app. So I suppose there is no a way to parse the given datetime format to ISO8601 that sql server, right?

Comment: I repeat, DateTime has no format. It's *your* code that parses the string. *Your* code should use the correct CultureInfo instead of the US CultureInfo. As for the Android app, ISO8601 is the defacto format in JSON. How did the date end up in a localized format? Shouldn't the *app* fix the bug? What does `The input comes from a android app.` mean anyway?  You receive an HTTP call from an Android app? Or something else?

Comment: Also, note that the `System.FormatException` is from the client app, not SQL Server. You can parse that specific string with DateTime.ParseExact("13/01/2021 17:35:38", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", null) instead of the culture spec. Consistent use of ISO 8601 formatted strings is the way to make your API culter agnostic.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this way, it should work:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(arrivalOnScene, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

[DateTime.ParseExact Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=net-5.0)